# Need to host the webcam output to some web site

Tags: webcam

i have new webcam. 
The software of the webcam can give out the webcam live moview to site.

I looking for some free good site that i can use for hosting my webcam live movie

Where can i find it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry there is no **FREE** webservice that will let stream your webcam to their website. It will eat their bandwidth , wont they ?

However, try to get some FTP account and download a program called "Dorgem" on your computer and let it run , so it will keep streaming your webcam data to your FTP.

**Update for Comment :**

Why not just use yahoo messenger ? Create 2 accounts (for yourself and for your baby's) Place your cam before your baby's cradle and sign-on to yahoo messenger with your baby's account and open your cam and set "Anyone can view my cam" (in the preferences). So when you go to your office , log on to your account , just click "View cam" of your baby's account. Job Done :)

Comment: I just want to connect the webcam to enable see my baby when i will be at work next week ( baby age is 4 month ... ) - there is no way to do it ?

Comment: because in the yahoo msg i can control on the webcam. The webcam that i have can be turn right or left or up and down from the http page that shows the video stream.

Comment: Do you want to control the direction of webcam from remote ?